# Generative / Discriminative model for linear regression

Tags: statistics, regression, machine-learning, linear-regression

> In [Murphy's book](https://doc.lagout.org/science/Artificial%20Intelligence/Machine%20learning/Machine%20Learning_%20A%20Probabilistic%20Perspective%20%5BMurphy%202012-08-24%5D.pdf), page 242-243, it is asked to describe the advantages and disadvantages of the generative model for linear regression, compared with the standard discriminative approach.
>
> I'm looking for a complete answer to this, since it is not clear what to say.

What I got so far:

Disvantages:

1. It is an indirect method, since we have to estimate the joint distribution $Y,\mathbf{X}$ before finding the optimal predictor;
2. There are too many parameters to estimate, namely $\frac{(p+1)(p+2)}{2}$ in the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ of the joint distribution, plus the $p+1$ parameters for the mean of $\textbf{X}$ and $Y$.

Advantages:

1. Better accuracy for small training sets;
2. One can use the joint distribution to generate new data similar to the existing data.

There is also one disadvantage that I don't understand so well: it is said that the number of needed parameters is $p+1$. I think that this refers to $\textbf{w}$ and $w_0$, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the parameters, I would take it to mean the parameters of the mean of the joint distribution $p(X,Y)$. Assuming $X\in\mathbb{R}^p, Y\in\mathbb{R}$, then the joint distribution has $\mu=(\mu_X,\mu_Y)\in\mathbb{R}^{p+1}$.

Note that, as you say $w\in\mathbb{R}^p,w_0\in\mathbb{R}$, so there are indeed $p+1$ parameters, which is also a reasonable answer in my opinion.

---

Your list seems complete.
Only thing I might add is a disadvantage, that generative models tend to perform slightly worse on their overall error rate (perhaps unsurprising since they are trying to model more things). Hence why people still tend to prefer discriminative models (or one reason anyway). This is not specific to linear models though.